# How to debug "Cannot read property 'module' of undefined" in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, karma-jasmine

I get this error running scripts/test.bat via console

```
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
```

I am under Windows 7 as you can notice and using Angular Seed.

Comment: Hard to tell, as you've posted no code, but I'm betting you're not requiring angular in the right order, so the angular object you're trying to call "angular.module" on is undefined. But again, it would be much simpler if you could post your karma configuration file and any other code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've missed loading angular-mock library before listing test files in karma configuration under files:[] section. You need angular-mock library loaded before listing any test files. Beware that angular-mocks library in turn expects angular.js to be loaded before it.

refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock